# How to set UserAgent using WebEngine of JavaFX prior to JDK8?

Tags: java, javafx, user-agent, javafx-webengine

I am using JDK7 for development and I want to set a user agent using JDK7 JavaFX Webengine.

Can anybody help me out with source code which sets the useragent using javaFX webengine using JDK7?

I have searched a lot but the only way is using JDK8 but I have to must use JDK7 to support Windows and MAC build.